# Deriving the distribution of $X^p$ if $X$ is Weibull distributed and estimating the parameters

Tags: maximum-likelihood, weibull-distribution

I am stuck with the following problem and hope somebody can help spotting the error. I am not sure if it's a simple math or programming glimbse or whether the issue is more complex (e.g. concerning identification).

Let $X$ be Weibull distributed, that is

$$ f_x(x;a,b) = \frac{a}{b} \left(\frac{x}{b}\right)^{a-1} \exp \left(-\left(\frac{x}{b}\right)^a \right).$$

**Problem**: what is the density of the distribution of $Y=X^p$ and how to estimate a, b, p, when a sample from $Y$ is observed?

We have:

$$ f_y(y; a,b,p) = f_x\bigg( y^{\frac{1}{p}} \bigg)\frac{1}{p} y^{\frac{1}{p}-1} 
\\= \frac{a}{b} \bigg( \frac{y^{\frac{1}{p}}}{b} \bigg)^{a-1} \exp \bigg(- (\frac{y^{\frac{1}{p}}}{b})^a \bigg) \frac{1}{p} y^{\frac{1}{p}-1}
\\= \frac{a}{b^ap} y^{\frac{1}{p}a - 1} \exp \bigg(- (\frac{y^{\frac{1}{p}}}{b})^a \bigg)$$

I do not see how to usefully simplify this further. Are there any arithmetic errors?

Now I wrote `R` code to test this result and do maximum likelihood estimation using `optim`. The ML estimation uses the log likelihood with likelihood contribution of observation $y_i$ equal to

$$\log a - a \log b - \log p + \bigg(\frac{1}{p}a-1 \bigg) \log y_i -  \bigg (\frac{y_i^{\frac{1}{p}}}{b} \bigg)^a  .$$

The implemented log likelihood is

```
    log_likelihood_y <- function(par, y) {
  a = exp(par[1])
  b = exp(par[2])
  p = exp(par[3])
  # Calculate each term of the log-likelihood
  term1 <- log(a) - log(p) - a * log(b)
  term2 <- ((a - p) / p) * log(y)
  term3 <- - (y^(1/p)/b)^a
  
  # Combine terms and normalize by the number of observations
  log_likelihood <- sum(term1 + term2 + term3)
  log_likelihood <- log_likelihood / length(y)

  # Handle potential numerical issues
  if(is.nan(log_likelihood) || is.infinite(log_likelihood)) {
    log_likelihood <- -Inf
  }
  
  return(-log_likelihood)
}
```

The optimizer is:

```
fit_model <- function(y, init = c(1,1,1), method = "BFGS") {
  fit <- optim(par = init,
               fn = log_likelihood_y,
               y = y,
               method = method)
  
  # Transform parameters back to the original scale
  estimates <- exp(fit$par)
  
  return(estimates)
}
```

And the code is run is follows:

```
x = rweibull(1e3, shape = 1, scale = 2)
p = 1/2
summary(x)
y = x^p
summary(y)
fit_model(y = y)
```

The estimates are off. Where do I go wrong?

**Edit Note**: I fixed the error in the Weibull formula noted by @Jarle Tufto. However the parameters do not estimate well. I noticed that if I fix *one* of the parameters to its true value, the other 2 estimate without bias. This seems to point to an identification issue. Is this problem not identified maybe?

**Edit Note 2**: I just realized that now we can set $$a' = a/p \\ b'=b^p$$ and find that Y is Weibull distributed with parameters a' and b'. I suppose the conclusion is that p is not separately identifiable from a and b, is it?

Comment: For a start, in your first equation inside the exponential, $x/b$ only rather than $(-x/b)$ is raised to the $a$th power.

Comment: @JarleTufto Sorry I do not see what you mean. Could you be more specific?

Comment: No, I can't be much more specific than that!  Your expression for the density of $X$ is clearly incorrect.  For example, if $a=1/2$ you would be taking the square root of a negative number.

Comment: @JarleTufto I see. I think it is $\exp (- (\frac{x}{b})^a )$, right?

Comment: Yes, and that changes what follows.

Comment: @JarleTufto I fixed the error but I still do not get the correct estimates. Could you check again if there's anything else going wrong?

Comment: +1 Your edit note 2 is correct.

Comment: By inspection or definition, a variable $X$ has a Weibull distribution when some power of $X$ has an Exponential distribution.  *Ergo,* $X^p$ obviously has a Weibull distribution, albeit with a different power (related to $p$ through the laws of exponentiation).  This all perhaps becomes more obvious when you examine the distribution function (CDF) rather than the density. This very description even suggests an effective way to compute an MLE: search for a power $q$ for which $X^q$ has approximately an Exponential distribution (and, in the process, estimate its parameter).